# Checking if an object meets certain criteria to amend to certain Entity Objects?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am trying to check if a class has only numeric values in it and then return a `bool`, however, some instances there may be non numeric chars in an object that should only contain numeric values.

At the present I am using reflection to loop through the object (Which in some cases can have up 200 properties) and then check the property value with `Regex` to see if it is a numeric value. The reason for the regex instead of `Int.TryParse` or `Int64.TryParse` is b/c every now and again a non integer value is mixed in with the text, but I know the file is an all integer file from the way it is setup. This however is not the issue as the Regex is working as expected.

The structure of the `StringCsv` and `IntergerCsv` Entities are different (What I mean is that the structure of the CSV's with string's and int's are fundamentally different) , but I need to save the data to an Entity that is consistent, which means I need to check which CSV is being imported to differentiate between the methods needed to save to the database. ie, There is a date column, but it differs between the `Interger` CSV and the `String` CSV.

Also, I can't add the data dirrectly into the Entities `StringCsv` and `IntergerCsv` b/c they need an `Id` which is a `Guid` and the CSV file does not contain that, which is why I read to the the class `GovernmentCsvRecord` and then covert the object to the Entity.

Below are samples of CSV files, sorry I can't post actual values.

The **string** file
[image]

The **Int** file
[image]

I should also mention that the first property will always be a GUID, that also needs to be taken into consideration. (I should probably be skipping that property anyway in my current code, but obviously don't.)

I should also mention I am using a [custom library](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to import the CSV files.

To check the value is numeric:

```
static bool IsMatch(string str)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[abcd][\d0-9]{5}$|[\d0-9]",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

Loop through each property and use above code to check the value,

```
static bool IsNumericFile<T>(List<T> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        List<string> values
                = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                    .Select(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null))
                    .Where(s => s != null)
                    .Select(s => s.ToString())
                    .Where(str => str.Length > 0)
                    .ToList();

        foreach (var propertyString in values)
        {
            var isNumeric = IsMatch(propertyString);
            //Jump out if non numeric value is found
            if (!isNumeric) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Reading the file,

```
// Get the data from the CSV
static List<T> ImportCsv<T>(string file, string delimeter = ",", bool hasHeader = false)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimeter;
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader;
        csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
        csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
        csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"); 

        return csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
    }
}


//Convert the data to the required entities
public IEnumerable<StringCsv> ReadStringCsvFromFile(string filePath)
{
    return ImportCsv<GovernmentCsvRecord>(filePath).Skip(3).Select(GovernmentCsvRecord.StringCsvGovernmentToEntity);
}

public IEnumerable<IntegerCsv> ReadIntCsvFromFile(string filePath)
{
    return ImportCsv<GovernmentCsvRecord>(filePath).Skip(3).Select(GovernmentCsvRecord.IntCsvGovernmentToEntity);
}
```

I am purposefully not posting the complete `GovernmentCsvRecord` object as it is an object with 200 string properties. I have posted the class with limited properties to illustrate how the class is set up with its properties and functions.

I convert to each entity via the functions in the `GovernmentCsvRecord`, `StringCsvGovernmentToEntity` and `IntCsvGovernmentToEntity`.

The `StringCsv` entity

```
public class GovernmentCsvRecord
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    //etc 200 properties in class

    public static StringCsv StringCsvGovernmentToEntity(GovernmentCsvRecord data)
    {
        StringCsv entity = new StringCsv();
        entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        entity.Col1 = data.Col1;
        entity.Col2 = data.Col2;
        //etc until 200 properties are filled
    }
    //The `IntegerCsv` entity

    public static IntegerCsv IntCsvGovernmentToEntity(GovernmentCsvRecord data)
    {
        IntegerCsv entity = new IntegerCsv();
        entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        entity.Col1 = data.Col1;
        entity.Col2 = data.Col2;
        //etc until 200 properties are filled
    }
 }
```

Then the usage,

```
List<StringCsv> StringList = new List<StringCsv>();
List<IntegerCsv> IntList = new List<IntegerCsv>();

StringList = ReadStringCsvFromFile(FileName).ToList();
if (!IsNumericFile(StringList))
{
    IntList = ReadIntCsvFromFile(FileName).ToList();
}

if (IntList.Count > 0)
{
    //Do stuff with intList
}
else
{
    //Do stuff with stringList
}
```

At present, it takes about 8 to 10ms to complete a check of one object, so performance wise it is not a huge issue, but I was wondering if there maybe was a better approach to do something like this?

Comment: I voted to reopen, but some things are still unclear. What's the difference between `StringCsv` and `IntegerCsv`? The name `ReadIntCsvFromFile` implies that it reads numeric data, but it's only called when the input contains non-numeric fields, so what does `IntCsvGovernmentToEntity` do that `StringCsvGovernmentToEntity` does not? And why read into `GovernmentCsvRecord` objects only to convert immediately afterwards - why not read directly into a `StringCsv` object, and convert that to an `IntegerCsv` when necessary?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, I edited the question to address those issues. Also, I don't know how to get the data into a unknown type and then check values, so I just checked if the object was a string file or not and proceeded from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Instead of throwing away that list of `GovernmentCsvRecord` objects after converting it to a `StringCsv` list, you could keep it around so you don't have to read the csv file again if the `IsNumericFile` check fails.
- It looks like you can validate the list of `GovernmentCsvRecord` objects directly instead of first converting them to `StringCsv` objects. However, with the way you're converting them, and taking the numeric check into account, it's probably better to read each row into an array of strings. Apparently the easiest way to do that is to give `GovernmentCsvRecord` a single `string[]` property. That lets you validate fields without having to use reflection.
- That regular expression can be simplified a lot. The first part matches strings like `"a12345"` - anything that starts with an a, b, c or d, followed by exactly 5 digits. The second part matches anything that contains at least one digit - which covers everything that the first part covers, and more, so just the second part is sufficient. Also note that `\d` matches decimal digits from a variety of scripts, including `0-9`, so `[\d0-9]` can be simplified to just `\d`. But you may want to use `0-9` instead, unless you also want to accept digits like `'೬'` and `'६'`.

Comment: +1. And you absolutely correct. As I was re-writing the question, saw I was doing a fair bit of redundant code. As you say, validate the `GovernmentCsvReord` class and then convert to the needed entities. Thanks for the advice on the Regex, I am not very good with it, so that helps enormously as well.

Comment: Another optimization is to create and reuse a single (compiled) `Regex` instance instead of calling the static `IsMatch` method, so the regex engine doesn't have to parse the pattern each time. Or, for such a simple pattern, `string.Any(char.IsDigit)` (for `\d`) or `string.Any(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')` (for `0-9`) is even faster.

Comment: Doing that instead of Regex brings 1500 line file with 200 properties down to 20ms from 30ms. One third faster is on just that is awesome. Overall I think I have reduced run time to half its original time it took. Thanks for the help.There are a couple more things I think I can do, but this has got me on the right track.